# Pegar id de elemento carregado dinãmicamente

Tags: php, jquery, html

Meu script contém três partes:

A primeira é a página de exibição (ex: home.php) nela faço include de outras duas páginas.

A segunda é uma página que faz uma consulta ao banco de dados e exibe os 5 primeiros resultados (ex: consult-1.php) esta é exibida por padrão.

A terceira é outra página que exibe mais 5 resultados a partir do ultimo id listado na home.php (ex: consult-2.php) quando o usuário demanda esta consulta, e a cada nova demanda exibe mais 5 resultados.

Os includes são feitos dentro de uma div e para retornar resultados da página "consult-2.php" eu uso o seguinte:

```
    $(".minha-div:last").after(data); //Aonde "data" é o retorno de "consult-2.php"
```

Os elementos exibidos tanto pela página de pré-load "consult-1.php" quanto pela página "consult-2.php" possuem o retorno de seus respectivos "ids" examinando com inspetor posso velos claramente porém no script preciso pegar esses ids em uma função "click" com jquery.

O problema reside exatamente ai, só consigo pegar os "ids" dos resultados exibidos pela página "consult-1.php" os resultados de "consult-2.php" embora sejam exibidos e possuam "ids" não consigo capturá-los e nem se quer exibilos com um simples alert :(

Desde de já grato por qualquer ajuda!

HOME.PHP

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['last_msg_id'])){
      $last_msg_id = $_GET['last_msg_id'];
  }
  if(isset($_GET['action'])){
      $action=$_GET['action'];
  }else{ 
    $action = ''; 
  }

  if($action != "get"){
?>

   <div id="Minha-Div">

       <?php include('consult-1.php'); ?>

       <div id="last_msg_loader"></div>

       <?php 
         }else{
           include('consult-2.php');
           exit();
         }
       ?> 
   </div>
```

CONSULT-1.PHP

```
<?php
   $Busca = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM minha-tabela ORDER By id DESC LIMIT 5");
   $Busca->execute();

   while($fetch = $Busca->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        $id =  $fetch['id'];
        $conteudo =  $fetch['conteudo'];

?>

<div id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="message_box">

       <div><?php echo $conteudo; ?></div>

</div>

<?php 
   }// Fechamento do "while" !
?>
```

CONSULT-2.PHP

```
<?php
   $last_msg_id = $_GET['last_msg_id'];
   $Busca = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM minha-tabela WHERE id < '$last_msg_id' ORDER By id DESC LIMIT 5");
   $Busca->execute();

   while($fetch = $Busca->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        $id =  $fetch['id'];
        $conteudo =  $fetch['conteudo'];

?>

<div id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="message_box">

       <div><?php echo $conteudo; ?></div>

</div>

<?php 
   }// Fechamento do "while" !
?>
```

Utilizo a rolagem da barra scroll para iniciar a função que exibe mais itens:

SCRIPT.JS

```
// Verifica scroll e chama função 
$(window).scroll(function(){
   if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
      last_msg_funtion();
   }
});
// Função que busca
function last_msg_funtion(){
    // Verifica se há conteúdo na tela...caso haja usamos "return"
    if($('#last_msg_loader img').length){
       //Isso evita duplicatas caso haja conteúdo carregado!
       return;
    }
    // salvamos o ultimo id da lista
    var ID = $(".message_box:last").attr("id");

    // Mostramos imagem de carregamento
    $('#last_msg_loader').html('<img src="load.gif">');
    // Enviamos o post (para esta mesma página)
    $.post("home.php?action=get&last_msg_id="+ID, function(data){
      // se a resposta não for vazia...
      if(data != ""){
          // Inserimos ela
          $(".message_box:last").after(data);     
      }
      // Limpamos o .gif
      $('#last_msg_loader').empty();

    });
};// Fechamos a função
```

Comment: Pode colocar o código do php que têm? senão é dificil imaginar o que têm.

Comment: Code adicionado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não se se entendi corretamente, mas se você está querendo disparar um evento "click" em um elemento criado dinamicamente utilize o on() do elemento BODY e não o click() direto. Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
$("body").on(
    "click",
    ".classe_do_elemento", // pode ser ID tbm
    function (event) {
        // sua lógica aqui
    }
);
```

Comment: Um grande obrigado era isso mesmo!